# Restructuring DataFrame Based on Single Column Values

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am trying to move data from one column to another based on multiple existing values. I researched and found a simple solution for a single column - as seen in the current code below. However, I would like a way to do it for all rows. I've been trying to research a way, but cannot seem to find a way to apply a possible loop to this function. Any help would be great. I am using the latest version of R, and RStudio. Thanks!

CURRENT DATAFRAME:

```
Row #People
A   3
A   2
A   2
B   1
B   1
C   3
C   3
C   2
C   1
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
Row: A B C
     3 1 3
     2 1 3
     2   2
         1
```

Current Code:

```
files <- read.csv("SampleData3.csv", header = T)
subset<-as.data.frame(files[files$RowID == A, "DisRank"])
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library("qpcR")
do.call(qpcR:::data.frame.na,split(df$X.People, df$Row))
   A  B C
1  3  1 3
2  2  1 3
3  2 NA 2
4 NA NA 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DatamineR. Your solution works perfect for me. I would never have figured that out. Very useful package!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` way of doing it using `tidyr::spread`.  You'll also need to add row numbers, which I get rid of in the end by using `dplyr`'s `select(-id)`.

Start by creating the data:

```
df = read.table(text="Row People
A   3
A   2
A   2
B   1
B   1
C   3
C   3
C   2
C   1", header = TRUE)
```

Now do the work:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by(Row) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(key = Row, value = People) %>% 
    select(-id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help lebelinoz. Couldn't get this to work with my dataset unfortunately. Perhaps I did something wrong. I did get it to work with the above solution from DatamineR. I took note of your code however and tidyverse looks like a useful package

Comment: @Alexander Maybe because my data isn't exactly like yours?  Since you hadn't actually included sample data in your, I've edited my answer to include it.  And do take a look at `tidyverse` (which includes great packages such as `ggplot2`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`):  I use it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

How about `reshape2::dcast(.~Row, data = dta, fun.aggregate=list)[, -1]`. This will give you a `data.frame` with list in a cell.

#### Added for output

```
        A    B          C
1 3, 2, 2 1, 1 3, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: How would you then translate the lists into a dataframe?

Comment: I have added the output, where A, B and C are in a data.frame while each columns are list. It is a data.frame of list. The 1 in the second line is `rowname`

Comment: Thanks for your help Rimalaya. I couldn;t quite get this one to work for me- but likely I did something wrong. Nonetheless, I got it to work for me with the above solution.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, your desired DataFrame is not a valid DataFrame in R. So it is impossible. You should explain why you want something like that. There are other data types like lists that can store data in a structure like that, but I haven't a clue what you want to do afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But, you appear to be incorrect since the above solution has worked for me.

Comment: Okay, just understand that your desired dataframe is not the same as the dataframe produced by the selected answer. NA is a special value that is different than blank space. Make sure to understand the difference https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/

It will save you headaches to understand the differences early on.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I see what you are saying now - makes full sense. I should have been more clear in my description.